# quadratic form over polynomial rings

Tags: polynomials, quadratic-forms

If a quadratic form $f(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^{2}$ is defined over a polynomial ring $R(t)$, R is a commutative ring with unity, then, how does a uni modular transformation is defined?
Also, what is the matrix associated with this?

Do I get any references on this

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial ring $R[t]$ (not $R(t)$) is, among other things, a commutative ring with unity.

So, the definitions for quadratic forms over commutative rings with unity apply.

Comment: Hurkyl, do I get any material on this